# How to echo data from one view to another one in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two function in my Main Controller, one is for the normal user data, and the other one is for updating the results...
How is it possible to echo out nicely in the index view?

```
public function index()
{
    $data['adat'] = $this->Sajat->get_data();
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}


public function update_st() {
    $id = $this->input->post('did');
    $name = $this->input->post('dname');
    $data = array(
    'Ticket' => $this->input->post('dticket'),
    'Date' => $this->input->post('ddate')
    );

    echo $name; // **comment
    $this->Sajat->update_reg($id,$name,$data);
    $this->index();

}
```

**comment = it works but its really ugly, i want to style it and I want to echo to the index view.... Is it possible??**
How can I pass

```
$name
```

from  update_st() view to index() view? Thanks for helping me out.

Model from comment

```
public function get_data() { 
   $this->db->select('*'); 
   $this->db->from('users'); 
   $query = $this->db->get(); 
   return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: Show hows your get_data function looks. The convention says that you call the model function inside controller, your function returns some data, you pass them to the view, maybe wpapped with $data array, or use $this->load->vars(). No need to load view inside view for that.

Comment: This is my get_data()

`public function get_data() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }`

Comment: @gazrobur if you need to add more code to your question you can click on the edit button below tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In update_st function you can simply pass data like this,

```
$data['name'] = $name;
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I was too tired to find it out. Thank you for your kind help